# Docker File Error no such file or directory: unkno

Tags: docker, rust, cryptography

Trying to build a pkt miner image in order to deploy to akash.

Keep getting this error

````
Error invoking remote method 'docker-start-container': 
Error: (HTTP code 400) unexpected - 
OCI runtime create failed: 
container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: 
"./target/release/packetcrypt": 
stat ./target/release/packetcrypt: no such file or directory: unknown```
````

My Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    curl
RUN apt-get update
RUN curl -y --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
RUN apt install make
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install gcc git 
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN git clone https://github.com/cjdelisle/packetcrypt_rs

ENV PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/packetcrypt_RS

CMD [ "~/", ".cargo/bin/cargo", "build", "--release" ]

CMD [ "./target/release/packetcrypt", "ann", "-p", "pkt1qd5skpmelkwvzy5vppqhafvmx0n5kqy97eglp00", "http://pool.pkteer.com" ]
```

I've tried adding WORKDIR

Can't seem to get rid of the error no matter what I do. I have a feeling im missing something obvious

Comment: The `cargo build` command never runs, since it's a `CMD` and the second `CMD` replaces it.  Do you mean it to be a `RUN` instruction so that it runs as part of the image build?

Comment: Perhaps also ask at https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: hmmm lemme try it

Comment: It's suppose to a command thats executed from the repository that gets installed so i think command is proper

Comment: `RUN` definitely seems like what you want. That way `docker build` will compile the code, and `docker run` will run it. `CMD` is what runs when `docker run` is called, so you's be compiling the Rust code every time you run it even if it hasn't changed.

Comment: The 2nd cmd overwrites the first